# How will DNS changes affect my azure site?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

If I change my DNS settings, will my azure website lose the custom domain that is already assigned to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the domain validation is performed only at the time of adding the URL to website. It is not checked / re-checked on a periodic basis. Once you add the custom domain to a site, it will remain there unless you remove it manually.

Here is the link that explains more about Mapping an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

Comment: Thanks for your help.